# Is there a way to modify / extend psql interactive with functions and aliases?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am using postgreSQL since a few days so I am a bit of a noob, please bear with me.

My question is about mega-functions really:

Consider a huge function like this one:

```
  SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation",
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "size"
  FROM pg_class C
  LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
  WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
  ORDER BY pg_relation_size(C.oid) DESC
  LIMIT 20;
```

It gives me the size of the database back, very nice.

But my poor brain is never able to remember that. Is there a way to
extend psql and use aliases or something like that?

So that I could then use something like this here:

database_sizes?

As a function call and it tells me the size?

Right now I copy / paste all the time and it kinda sucks :/

Comment: It doesn't return the size of the database. It returns the sizes of the 20 largest tables or indexes in *one* database. Is that really what you want?

Comment: You might to go through the GUI tools listed in the Postgres Wiki. Some of them can do what you want: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Comment: Very good idea, though, I'd quite like to be able to bind arbitrary SQL snippets to backslash command macros.

Comment: Can you remember `select pg_database_size('db_name')`?

Comment: Hi - unfortunately select pg_database_size('nodes'); does not work, it tells me: 'database "nodes" does not exist' though I get it to work with: SELECT * from nodes; so I am a little confused. Your function would be quite easy to remember I suppose, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Mike Sherrill 'Catcall', the above is an example. It is not so important what it does and more important whether I could use functions that I define instead for convenience. I can work with simple SQL statements okish, but the more complex ones like the above one just totally confuse me right now.

Comment: I understood it that via \i once could at least temporarily modify the database and extend it with functionality as Richard Huxton said. I could probably bundle all helpful SQL functions into a file, load it, play with the database then unload it. (To further clarify - right now I am on a windows machine and have to use putty to interface with the remote database, on an english keyboard. I normally have a german keyboard, so now my brain has to adapt to so many things... the more convenient I can make it to work with anything here, the better!)

Answer (score 0):

Not without creating functions in each database (which I assume you don't want to do).

However there's nothing to stop you sticking that in a little script file and just running it via `\i ~/pgscripts/bigtables.sql`. With filename auto-completion that's pretty simple to run.

Comment: Hmm ok so I can create specific functions in a database. Perhaps I could do so while I modify or work with it, and then once everything works, I can remove my custom functions again to 'clean up'. The ideal way would be to use a set of functions that I defined in a custom way - if that is not possible then that is fine for me. Thanks.

Comment: I can't think of a good reason why "CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION" shouldn't exist. That would be the ideal way - then you could create them in your .psql file. Try subscribing to the "hackers" mailing list on postgresql.org and asking if they'd be opposed to the idea.